# Is it illegal to modify a website using the developer console?

Tags: browser, bookmarklet

I am getting flak from the company I work for for having built a bookmarklet that makes one of their web applications more functional. It injects some code and new elements onto the page to augment the features of the site. Everything it does can be reproduced in the developer console.

They are accusing me of violating their Terms of Service, specifically the generic phrase

> "You agree that you will not modify, copy, distribute, transmit, display, perform, reproduce, publish, license, create derivative works from, frame in another web page, use on any other web site, transfer, or sell any information, software, lists of users, databases or other lists, products or services provided through or obtained from the site."

Does this hold water? What I'm doing is 100% local, modifying a rendered version of a website. I am not affecting their servers in any way. How should I respond to this?

Comment: I don't think stackoverflow is where you should post this question. Have a look at the other stavkexchange sites: https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: If your employer is telling you that and are actually quoting legalese like that at you to get you to stop, it would seem wise to stop.  They are your employer after all.